# Problem using Azure Functions and Azure Cosmos DB, returning "down for maintenance"

Tags: node.js, azure, cloud, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I am following this tutorial that creates an Azure Function trigged by http with output to CosmosDB.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-integrate-store-unstructured-data-cosmosdb

When I create just a simple Azure function it works ok, I trigge by http and the http response its ok.

But if create a new output to a ComosDB using the example code indicated in the tutorial  the function returns "THIS AZURE FUNCTIONS APP IS DOWN FOR MAINTENANCE"
when trigged.

Please be patience, until last week I was just a c++ programmer hahaha.

My steps:

Creating a CosmosDB account and a database called "testDb".

[image: CosmosDB account]

Creating a Function App:

[image]

When trigged using this code its ok.

[image]

Creating a CosmosDB output.

[image]

I change my code to this:

[image]

Now when I trigger by http the response is:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Grateful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Someone has reported same [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/17384). To conclude the solution: In portal> Platform features> App Service Editor. Right click on `app_offline.htm` and delete.

This file is generated to stop the function app when you install cosmosdb extension. It is supposed to be deleted automatically after extension being installed, there seems some problem with this feature, probably related to the slow file system in Consumption plan.

If you are trapped again later, try to turn this behavior off, add an `SCM_CREATE_APP_OFFLINE` App Setting to your app and set the value to `0`, check [official announcement](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/137#issue-362424427) for this feature.

Comment: For me, "Platform features" is a tab when you select the actual Function App.